# Printing a String in Reverse After Extracting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, reverse

I am trying to create a program in which the user inputs a statement containing two '!' surrounding a string. (example: hello all! this is a test! bye.) **I am to grab the string within the two exclamation points, and print it in reverse letter by letter.**  I have been able to find the start and endpoints that contain the statement, however I am having difficulties creating an index that would cycle through my variable `userstring` in reverse and print.

```
test = input('Enter a string with two "!" surrounding portion of the string:')
expoint = test.find('!')
     #print (expoint)
twoexpoint = test.find('!', expoint+1)
     #print (twoexpoint)
userstring = test[expoint+1 : twoexpoint]
     #print(userstring)


number = 0
while number < len(userstring) :
    letter = [twoexpoint - 1]
    print (letter)
    number += 1
```

Comment: What happens if the string has 3 ```!```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`twoexpoint - 1` is the last index of the string you need **relative to the input string**. So what you need is to start from that index and reduce. In your while loop:

```
letter = test[twoexpoint- number - 1]
```

Each iteration you increase `number` which will reduce the index and reverse the string.

But this way you don't actually use the `userstring` you already found (except for the length...). Instead of caring for indexes, just [reverse the `userstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python):

```py
for letter in userstring[::-1]:
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation we use regex to find the pattern
then we loop for every occurance and we replace the occurance with the reversed string. We can reverse string in python with `mystring[::-1]` (works for lists too)

[Python re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) Very usefull and you will need it all the time down the coder road :). happy coding!

[Very usefull article](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter7/)  Check it out!

```
import re # I recommend using regex

def reverse_string(a):
    matches = re.findall(r'\!(.*?)\!', a)
    for match in matches:
        print("Match found", match)
        print("Match reversed", match[::-1])
        for i in match[::-1]:
            print(i)

In [3]: reverse_string('test test !test! !123asd!')
Match found test
Match reversed tset
t
s
e
t
Match found 123asd
Match reversed dsa321
d
s
a
3
2
1
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo oups :) now much better fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

You're overcomplicating it. Don't bother with an index, simply use [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) on `userstring` to cycle through the characters themselves:

```
userstring = test[expoint+1:twoexpoint]
for letter in reversed(userstring):
    print(letter)
```

Or use a reversed slice:

```
userstring = test[twoexpoint-1:expoint:-1]
for letter in userstring:
    print(letter)
```